# Why is the set of all half-lines in the real numbers not a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

In a basic topology text by Anatole Katok, the following example of a set that is not a topological space is given:

If in the set of real numbers ${\mathbb R}$ we declare open (besides
the empty set and ${\mathbb R}$) all the half-lines {x ∈ ${\mathbb R}$|x ≥ a}, a ∈ ${\mathbb R}$, then we
do not obtain a topological space: the first and third axiom of topological
spaces hold, but the second one does not (e.g. for the collection of all half
lines with positive endpoints).

I don't see why the union axiom doesn't hold.  After all, isn't the union of any half-lines with positive endpoints just another half-line?

Answer (score 4):

The union of the positive half-lines is$$\bigcup_{b>0}\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq b\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x>0\}$$
This set is not of the form $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq a\}$ for any $a$.

Comment: But since a ∈  $\mathbb{R}$, why can't the a be any a > 0?